# Max limit of hibernate connection to mysql schema (need to connect 200 schemas in one db server).

Tags: mysql, hibernate, database-design, architecture

what is the max number of schema in database hibernate can connects without problems ? Working on a application where there are 200 tenants (separate schema, 200 database schema) in one database server. Bound to use hibernate. Please suggest architecture for app database communication.Memory footprint and others aspects also. Technology stack - Hibernate, spring jpa, smartgwt, mysql and jboss

Comment: Need to understand what type of application will have 200+ schema. I think it won't cause any issue connecting to these many schema but you have to create 200+ session factories to achieve this.

Comment: A solution can be providing access to tables to a single schema if it is allowed in your case. Your hibernate application will only have to connect to that single schema

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single connection to MySQL and access any number of databases:

```
SELECT ... FROM db1.table11 ...
SELECT ... FROM db2.table22 ...
```

Or use `JOIN`, `UNION`, etc, to access multiple databases in the same query:

```
SELECT ... FROM db1.table11 
           JOIN db2.table22 ...
```

If Hibernate won't let you do that, you have my condolences.

Comment: Thanks ! Is it fair to create 2500 tables in mysql under different database ? data size not being very(20 columns and 7k rows in six months in heavy tables roughly plus archiving in place) large - and hibernate talking to all of them. please through some light how does it sound

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions . Took next step and using AbstractRoutingDataSource spring which allows dynamic data source loading on the fly via spring. I am able to successfully manage transactions per session per schema BUT is it good choice for single session user and multiple schema access. Say a user wants to update same tables in both schema ?